# angular2 webpack large bundle size with sass

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, webpack

I have webpack bundle size issue which is cause by the sass styles...

I have many angular2 components which I design using the materialize-css library. I use the `@extend` instead of putting the materialize-css classes inside my html to encapsulate the library from the html itself.

The issue I'm having is extremely large bundle size with webpack because each component's sass imports the materialize-css package and because the style of the component is loaded using `raw` loader it gets embedded into the bundle js file. So what I get is huge bundle with the same materialize-css styles for every single component.

Just for comparing I compiled my application with all the styles commented out and the bundle size is 1.08MB when with styles included it is 5.26MB

Can anyone point me to the proper solution?

Thanks!

EDIT:
My webpack definitions:

Webpack.common:

```
import * as webpack from 'webpack';
import {Configuration} from 'webpack';
import * as path from 'path';
import {PathHelper} from '../../common/pathHelper';
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

process.env.ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;

export var webpackCommonConfiguration: Configuration = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/app/polyfills.ts',
    'app': './src/app/app.ts',
    'signin': './src/app/signinApp.ts',
    'vendor': './src/app/vendor.ts',
    'design': './src/app/design.scss'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', 'scss']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts'
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: PathHelper.getPathFromRoot('src', 'app', 'modules'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!resolve-url!sass?sourceMap')
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: PathHelper.getPathFromRoot('src', 'app', 'modules'),
        loader: 'raw!sass'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: PathHelper.getPathFromRoot('src', 'app', 'modules'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!resolve-url!css?sourceMap')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: PathHelper.getPathFromRoot('src', 'app', 'modules'),
        loader: 'raw!resolve-url'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'signinCommon',
      chunks: ['signin', 'vendor'],
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'homeCommon',
      chunks: ['app', 'vendor'],
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
      }
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      // Required for the velocity plugin to be loaded correctly (used in materialize css)
      "window.$": "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery",
      "root.jQuery": "jquery"
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: PathHelper.getPathFromRoot('src', 'app', 'views', 'signin.html'),
      filename: 'signin.html',
      chunks: ['polyfills', 'signinCommon', 'design', 'vendor', 'signin']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: PathHelper.getPathFromRoot('src', 'app', 'views', 'home.html'),
      filename: 'home.html',
      chunks: ['polyfills', 'homeCommon', 'design', 'vendor', 'app']
    })
  ]
}
```

Webpack.prod:

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
import * as webpack from 'webpack';
import {Configuration} from 'webpack';
import {webpackCommonConfiguration} from './webpack.common.config'
import {PathHelper} from '../../common/pathHelper';

interface IProductionConfiguration extends Configuration {
  htmlLoader: any;
}

var config: IProductionConfiguration = {

  devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    path: PathHelper.getPathFromRoot('dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
  },

  htmlLoader: {
    minimize: false // workaround for ng2
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css')
  ]
}

export var webpackProductionConfig: Configuration =
  webpackMerge(webpackCommonConfiguration, config);
```

Edit2:
Component example:

credits.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'credits',
  template: require('./credits.component.html'),
  styles: [require('./credits.component.scss')]
})
export class CreditsComponent {
}
```

credits.component.html:

```
<footer class="page-footer credits-footer">
  <div class="footer-copyright">
    <div class="container">
    © 2016 Created by Slava Shpitalny
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

credits.component.scss:

```
@import '~materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss';

:host{

  .page-footer.credits-footer{
    @extend .blue;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

  }
}
```

Comment: updated my answer, hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't bundle to only single file. Bundle separatly like one for vendor one for pollyfills one for app and one for css. Use `ExtractTextPlugin` plugin to create own css file. Use webpack chunks for making life easier. Use code splitting for large application.

[Read more about it](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html)

In production mode you can use some plugins which can minnify your bundle, remove comments, remove unused code.

Comment: I added my webpack configuration. Can you give an example to what you mean?

Comment: it looks good. you are using code splitting and ExtractTextPlugin. are you getting design.css separately? [here is a seed i been working on, bit different](https://github.com/blinfo/angular2-webpack-seed)

Comment: Yes, the issue is because the components are compiled using the `raw` loader, the style ends up inside the component javascript file...This with the implementation of the `import` in sass creates the issue. Each time I import the `materialize-css` library it is coppied. After the raw loader runs, the style gets injected inside the component as a string, so it gets no treatment...

Comment: I added simple component example

Comment: I never worked with sass but I want to. As I can understand webpack should compile sass to css and later bundle that.

Comment: Yes, you can see the `raw!sass` loaders pipeline which compiles the scss files to css and then uses the raw loader to put it as string inside the component...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ViewEncapsulation.None` on your main app component, and import Materialize.scss into your app's SCSS file.  It will then be globally available and you will not need to import it into other components.

For example, your app component might look like this:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    styles: [require('./app.scss')],
    template: require('./app.html')
})
```

...and only your main app's SCSS file would contain the import:

```
@import '~materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss';
```

Note: Instead of importing materialize.css, you could just import the Materialize components you use.  This would make it more efficient.

If there are variables/mixins you want to use in your child components you can import them individually (**but don't import the entire Materialize scss!**).

For example, a child component might import `_variables.scss` and `_mixins.scss`, instead of just `materialize.scss`.

For example:

```
@import '~materialize-css/sass/components/_mixins.scss';
@import '~materialize-css/sass/components/_variables.scss';
```

Don't forget, vars/mixins will not be exported, only the CSS result of the SCSS transpilation, so if they are not used they will not add to the file size (unlike the main Materialize.scss file which contains lots of CSS classes too)

Comment: In order for the line `@extend` to work I need to import materialize into the component sass file, I will look into the minimum portion I need to import for it to work...

Comment: Yes, can't you just import _color.scss for this?

Comment: Ok, I went through all my components and imported only the needed files. There are still styles that are copied multiple times like: `_color`, `_variables`, `_typography`, `_global`, `_buttons`, `_grid` which I add in my common `_forms` style and other components. The bundle size now is 2.27MB, its great improvement but my application is going to get much larger with time, at least twice the number of components. So the minimum styles for the existing components add around 1.2MB, any other suggestions?

Comment: when you say 2.27mb, is that before minimization and bundling?  and before gzip in the browser?

Comment: after the mininization..before its 10 MB...gzip?

Comment: 10mb sounds a lot, but it might be fine, hard to tell without seeing your project.  Generally, you don't want to be importing the same CSS classes into more than one component. You're better off importing them into your app.scss, and making it use ViewEncaspulation.None. Alternatively, you could just make your own variables/mixin files that import from various materialize files. Then in your child components, just import your own vars/mixins where needed.

Comment: This is what I do, but the problem is when I use extend in the component I must add the import in the component file. When I do that it gets copied. Before adding the styles my app was around 4MB in minified, so they added 6MB